# JavaFX + SpringBoot, cant load css

Tags: java, css, javafx

[image]i need a help understanding what is happening in my project, anyways i have javafx with springboot:

i have folder structure like this :

So i want to access from my java/controller folder, and i need my css file that is under resources folder, in css folder.

I tried every possible way, to load my css and nothing seems to work except :

Directly loading css through fxml (which i wish to evade)
using this code also works, but only in IDE, if i create JAR it does not work anymore :

```
File f = new File("src/main/resources/css/main.css");
paneRoot.getStylesheets().add("file:///" + f.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"));
```

When i do check of f.exists() i get true, so path is ok, but when i use this :

```
paneRoot.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("src/main/resources/css/main.css").toExternalForm());
```

or

```
paneRoot.getStylesheets().add("src/main/resources/css/main.css");
```

it does not work,in first code line, where i use .toExternalForm(), program crashes reporting nullPointer.

Now i honestly do not know what is issues here, i tried with 2 different IDE-s, i tried clearing cashe, rebulding and cleaning application, but every time same issue.

If i need to provide further code, i will i just need to understand this.

Comment: `src` is the *source* folder. Why would you even expect this to be present at runtime? You should try something like `getClass().getResource("/css/main.css").toExternalForm()` (the path is resolved relative to the class path). To troubleshoot, you need to check the content of the *build* folder (not the source folder) and the jar file (from the command line, do `jar tf myfile.jar`).

Comment: just to make it clear, i tried almost every, path possible, the one i left last was just one of attempts, i even tried this one that you here showed. However i found the problem, issue was that i renamed application, and even though appeared that everything was ok, for some reasond i was not able to load files properly,recreating new application, and doing simple test, and everything worked ok.